# How do I see what custom values were used in a Helm release?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When I use `helm install` to install a chart into a Kubernetes cluster, I can pass custom values to the command to configure the release. `helm` must store them somewhere, because I can later rollback to them. However, I cannot find a way to view the values in the deployed version or the previous one.

I want to see what values will change (and confirm what values are set) when I rollback a release. I thought `inspect` or `status` might help with that, but they do different things. How can I see the values that were actually deployed?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To view what was actually deployed in a release, use [`helm get`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get/).

If you use `helm -n <namespace> get all <release-name>` you get all the information for the current release of `<release-name>` in namespace `<namespace>`<sup>†</sup>. You can specify `--revision` to get the information for a specific version, which you can use to see what the effect of `rollback` will be.

You can use `helm -n <namespace> get values <release-name>` to just get the values `install` used/computed rather than the whole chart and everything, or `helm -n <namespace> get manifest <release-name>` to view the generated resource configurations<sup>††</sup>.

Where this information is stored depends on the version of `helm` you are using:

- For version 3, it is ([by default](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends)) in a `secret` named `<release-name>.<version>` in the namespace where the release was deployed. The content of the secret is about the same as what was in the `helm` version 2 `configMap`
- For version 2: it is in a `configMap` named `<release-name>.<version>`, in the `kube-system` namespace. You can get more detail on that [here](http://technosophos.com/2017/03/23/how-helm-uses-configmaps-to-store-data.html).

<sup>†</sup>For `helm` version 2, use `helm get <release-name>` instead of `helm get all <release-name>`

<sup>††</sup>For `helm` version 2, release names had to be unique cluster-wide. For `helm` version 3, release names are scoped to namespaces, and the `helm` command operates on the "current" namespace unless you specify a namespace using the `-n` or `--namespace` command line option.

Comment: and don't forget specifying the namespace ```helm get values <release-name> -n NAMESPACE```

Comment: for Helm 3 it is needed to give the namespace as well. From Helm 3 release names are not cluster wide.

Comment: @YeasinArRahman @weshouman For helm 3, it is not necessarily required to specify the namespace. The "current" namespace (from the `KUBECONFIG` `context`) is assumed if you do not specify one.

Answer (score 15):

`helm get <release-name>` no longer works with Helm3. `helm get values <release-name>` does show the custom values used for the release. Note: to get all possible values for reference, use `helm show values <your-chart>` - this doesn't show the custom values though.