# How to get helm values and store it in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, powershell, visual-studio-code, kubernetes, helm3

I want to get helmchart values and store it in postgres database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511698/23310241